# Google input tools fonts are not rendering in the website

Tags: php

Google input tools fonts are not rendering in my website.

I am creating a website which support multi language to type. I have typed in malayalam and the font are showing correctly while trying and in the preview page it was showing like this:

```
à´®à´²à´¯à´¾à´³à´ à´à´¨àµà´¨à´¾ à´­à´¾à´· à´à´¤à´¿ à´®à´¹à´¤àµà´¤à´
```

In the database it was store like this

`<p>Ã Â´Â®Ã Â´Â²Ã Â´Â¯Ã Â´Â¾Ã Â´Â³Ã Â´Â‚ Ã Â´ÂŽÃ Â´Â¨Ã ÂµÂÃ Â´Â¨Ã Â´Â¾ Ã Â´Â­Ã Â´Â¾Ã Â´Â· Ã Â´Â…Ã Â´Â¤Ã Â´Â¿ Ã Â´Â®Ã Â´Â¹Ã Â´Â¤Ã ÂµÂÃ Â´Â¤Ã Â´Â‚&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`

I am new to php and I don't know why it was showing like this. I have included the my post page and preview code page in pastebin.

Post page: http://pastebin.com/94t9wXVU

Preview page: http://pastebin.com/SHUYpvUW

Comment: I am NOT part of those who gave negative vote. However i think your problem is a charset problem. Have you tried to change the charset of your page ?

Comment: john-max thank you for your reply.. I found an solution from another website same as stackoverflow. The mistake I have done is added below. As I can say who ever given negative vote will make user's like me to not post any question's in this website

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution.

change the collation to utf8_general_ci in the database because utf8_unicode_ci is requrid in mysql

Changed the line like this

$val=utf8_encode($description);
<--- Removed and

$val=$description; 
<--- added like this